# How to call reverse records in RoomDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, dao

How can I call reverse records?? I want to order by primary key values.

In Entity, PrimaryKey is autogenerated.

```
@Dao
public interface TodoDao {
    @Query( "SELECT " + Todo.COL_Item + " FROM " + Todo.TABLE_NAME)
    List<String> getAllItems();
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Asking multiple questions at once goes against how this site is designed. Feel free to ask the first question and link to it from the second question if they are related. This makes it easier to match the answers to the question, and increases you changes of getting the answers you want. If someone has the perfect answer to part 1, but not part 2 you don't want them not answering.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that, just edited post!

Answer (score 1):

For your first question you simply need to change this line

```
@Query("SELECT " + Todo.COL_Item + " FROM " + Todo.TABLE_NAME +" ORDER BY Column_Primary_Key DESC")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can can search `order by desc` in your query

```
@Query("select *from table_name order by your_primary_key desc")
fun getList() : LiveData<List<YourModelClass>>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question,

```
@Dao
public interface TodoDao {
    @Query( "SELECT " + Todo.COL_Item + " FROM " + Todo.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY "+ Todo.COL_YOUR_PRIMARY_KEY" DESC")
    List<String> getAllItems();
}
```

Next, you can make your columns unique to find out whether the data is already in the table or not.

```
@Entity(indices = {@Index(value = {"first_name", "last_name"},
        unique = true)})
class User {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
    public String firstName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
    public String lastName;
}
```

and then you can insert like,

```
try {
            // Execute insert function
        } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error inserting record", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```